# How to compile Wayland compositors based on wlroots in C using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, archlinux, window-managers, wayland

I am trying to learn how to make a Wayland compositor based on [wlroots](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots). Following their [wiki](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots/wiki/Getting-started), I am trying to compile tinywl.c ([github](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots/tree/master/tinywl)) file as an example with

`` gcc -o wm1 wm1.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags pixman-1` -DWLR_USE_UNSTABLE ``

and I get the error

`In file included from wm1.c:22: /usr/include/wlr/types/wlr_xdg_shell.h:14:10: fatal error: xdg-shell-protocol.h: No such file or directory 14 | #include "xdg-shell-protocol.h" |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`.

I also checked the makefile but still do not completely understand how to compile this. So, I wonder what are the steps exactly. I am running an Arch Linux and Swaywm works just fine on my machine(I assume there are no missing libraries). Thank you for your help.

Comment: It appears that wlroots has a dependency on the [Wayland xdg-shell Protocol](https://wayland-book.com/xdg-shell-basics.html), and the development components for that are not installed on your machine.  See also [this friendlier summary](https://wiki.tizen.org/Wayland_xdg-shell_protocol).

Comment: I checked this before, xdg-shell-protocols are somehow included in [wayland-protocols](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/wayland-protocols/) and I have it installed on my machine(Arch Linux).

Comment: Perhaps you have installed only the runtime components of wayland-protocols, not the development components.  Or perhaps the install is broken, or for some reason the library headers are not installed in an appropriate location (which could be construed as a particular case of "broken").  If you indeed have the needed header, but the compiler does not find it, then you will need to add its directory to the include path via a compiler option of the general form `-I/path/to/header/directory'.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the [Makefile](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots/blob/master/tinywl/Makefile) to build tinywl and it produced the xdg-shell-protocol.h and xdg-shell-protocol.c . Also, I just learned from Makefile that I should  probably use '-lwlroots  -lwayland-server  -lxkbcommon' when compiling.